# Multiple single insert and update vs bulk merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which holds around 1-2m rows of data.

I have a large number of users that will send update to the data in batches of 100 at a time.

To make this simple lets say the table looks like

```
ID, col1, col2... , val, UpdateTime
```

The data comes in the format of

```
col1, col2, ..., val, RetrievedTime
```

`col1, col2, ....` combined together makes a unique constraint and `val` is the value I'm interested in. `RetrievedTime` is the time which the date was retrieved.

I need to insert it into the table if it does not exist or update the `val` and `UpdateTime` if `RetrieveTime > UpdateTime`

Currently im inserting all the 100 rows into a temp table and doing an insert where not exists + update where exists to push (merge) the data to the actual table

I wonder if its better to make 100 insert + update calls individually

or

100 insert into temp table then one insert where not exists + update where exists

I.E.

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable Values(...)
INSERT INTO #TempTable Values(...)
INSERT INTO #TempTable Values(...)
INSERT INTO #TempTable Values(...)
... 100 rows

INSERT INTO ActualTable SELECT ... FROM #TempTable WHERE NOT EXISTS(...)
UPDATE ActualTable SET val = ... INNER JOIN #TempTable T ON ... WHERE T.col1 = ActualTable.col1
```

VS

Turn on IGNORE_DUP_KEY (Unique key duplicate will be throw exception. Instead it will skip and continue)

```
INSERT INTO ActualTable VALUES (...)
INSERT INTO ActualTable VALUES (...)
INSERT INTO ActualTable VALUES (...)
INSERT INTO ActualTable VALUES (...)
... 100 inserts

UPDATE ActualTable SET val = ..., UpdateTime=RetrieveTime WHERE col1=.. AND col2=.. AND RetrieveTime > UpdateTime
UPDATE ActualTable SET val = ..., UpdateTime=RetrieveTime WHERE col1=.. AND col2=.. AND RetrieveTime > UpdateTime
UPDATE ActualTable SET val = ..., UpdateTime=RetrieveTime WHERE col1=.. AND col2=.. AND RetrieveTime > UpdateTime
UPDATE ActualTable SET val = ..., UpdateTime=RetrieveTime WHERE col1=.. AND col2=.. AND RetrieveTime > UpdateTime
... 100 updates
```

Both seem to run pretty fast on my local environment but when the server is under load im getting quite a lot timeout. So I'm wondering which method would be better performance for highly concurrent environment and why?

Comment: Usually doing things in batches performs better, but like always, you should test how it goes in your case. You could also use merge statement, which probably doesn't differ much from insert + update. Instead of UpdateTime I'd use rowversion, since it works automatically so you don't have to always remember to update it.

Comment: Depending on where the data is coming from, you might also be able to do one insert / load into tempdb instead of 100 different inserts (SqlBulkCopy, table valued parameters etc)

Comment: @JamesZ would it reduce the likelihood of deadlock if I do inserts update individually vs batch?

Comment: If it's inside transaction, then doing 100 different inserts will definitely increase the likelihood that other process is also updating the same rows at the same time